# How to pass a php variable containing js script to a function?

Tags: javascript, php, parameters, move-uploaded-file

I have a php variable `$ext` used to take value of a js variable `fp`

```
$nam = $_POST['subject'];
$ext = "<script>document.writeln(fp);</script>";
```

I need to pass the variables into `move_uploaded_file` function like this

```
$x = 'uploads/' . $nam . "." . $ext; // a temp variable to join those variables

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $x))
```

Is it possible ?

Comment: You can't, JS is executed on the client, PHP is executed on the server at very different times. Consider to include `fb` value into a form control element, like `input type="hidden"`. Also, it's dangerous to let a client to name a file on your server, you've at least to validate it carefully to avoid attacks.

Comment: In PHP, you can pass a string that contains JavaScript code as an argument to a function by encapsulating the string in single or double quotes. For example:


<?php
$jsScript = "<script>console.log('Hello, World!')</script>";

function passJSScript($jsScript) {
  echo $jsScript;
}

passJSScript($jsScript);
?>